# how to separate value of span id to another file?

Tags: javascript, html

Good day, I just want to separate the "span id" into another file so it'll be easier to edit for someone who doesn't know much about HTML codes.

example :

```
<span id="stock1"></span>
<span id="stock2"></span>
<span id="stock3"></span>
```

separated file for "stock" values (javascript? sry idk how to use it) :

```
stock1="5"
stock2="5"
stock3="8"
```

well basically the values in the separated "stock" file will appear in the HTML. but I don't know how to pull this one out. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to get the span elements by their Id and edit them accordingly with the following JavaScript.

```
var stock1 = 5;
var stock2 = 5;
var stock3 = 8;

document.getElementById("stock1").innerHTML=stock1;
document.getElementById("stock2").innerHTML=stock2;
document.getElementById("stock3").innerHTML=stock3;
```

You can then either put it in the HTML file using a `<script>` tag, or create a separate .js file, linking it in like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="fileName.js"></script>`

Comment: just tried the code and it works! thank you for answering my question in a short moment.